# Inconsistent output from python program

Tags: python

This question is related to my earlier post:-

I ran this program in the IDLE interpreter:

```
      import os
      def rename_files():
            file_list = os.listdir("C:\prank")
            print (file_list)
```

Sometimes, this program executes as intended, i.e. the list of filenames specified in the argument gets printed in the Python shell. but other times, the shell simply restarts without any other output, the code itself seems fine.
I tried prefixing the argument with  'r' so that the program accepts the file path 'as is'. Same result.
I have tried changing directories, with the same result.

What else should I try? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this the full program? this is just a function, you need to call it, too. I'd expect no output when this is run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function you define:

```
import os

def rename_files(path):
     file_list = os.listdir(path)
     print (file_list)


rename_files(r"C:\prank")
```